# How do I instantiate an AVPlayer with a local file path in Swift 3 on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer

In Swift 3 on iOS, how do I create an [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) instance with a local video file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [URL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) using the main bundle's [url(forResource:withExtension:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1411540-url) method. Then instantiate the [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) using its [init(url:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1385706-init) constructor. Here's the code for how to do this:

```
let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "videos/video", withExtension: "mp4")!
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
```